# Reference for using ERB templates in a Java app (via JRuby)

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, erb

I have a legacy Ruby command line tool that uses (user supplied) ERB templates to format data.   I am required to rewrite this tool in Java but I need to avoid having everyone rewrite their ERB templates in a different template language.

I think I can do this with embedded JRuby but I have never used it.

Are there any good examples or reference for using ERB from Java apps?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2006/jw-0717-ruby.html) you can see at listing 6 how to call ruby from java with jruby.

And to use ERB is very easy :D

```
require 'erb'

# `binding` returns all variables declared in
# this scope, so they can be used in templates
#
ERB.new(File.read('file/path')).result(binding)
```

Comment: ok, jruby is great but now I have to figure out how to get ERB into the JAR :-( require "erb" fails with "no such file to load -- erb"

Comment: Use the jruby-complete jar, that comes with the gem pre-installed

Comment: The link is gone, backup copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607234553/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2006/jw-0717-ruby.html), but I would further suggest copying the relevant section into your answer.